# How to get the subdomain and domain in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

For example, I have URL `subdomain.example.com`.

How can I get the *subdomain* and *domain* from the URL in `.htaccess`?

I need to do something like:

```
RewriteRule (.*) example.com/subdomain/index.php
```

I figured it out for a *subdomain*, but still no luck for the *domain*.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.example.com
RewriteRule (.*) example.com/%1/index.php
```

Comment: Is there always only 1 subdomain and 1 domain? Or would `a.b.c.test.com` be possible?

Comment: only 1 subdomain and 1 domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(^.*)\.example.com
> RewriteRule (.*) example.com/%1/index.php
> ```

The same principle applies for the domain (although the *CondPattern* you are using here appears to be invalid?). It looks like you need the domain+TLD (basically, everything after the subdomain), so try something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.(.+?)\.?$
RewriteRule ![^/]+/[^/]+/index\.php$ %2/%1/index.php [L]
```

The `(.+?)` part of the *CondPattern* grabs the subdomain (the `?` makes it non-greedy). The `(.+?)` part grabs the domain (remaining part of the *host*), again this is non-greedy to avoid matching the optional trailing dot on a fully qualified domain (eg. `subdomain.example.com.`).

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `![^/]+/[^/]+/index\.php$` prevents a rewrite loop (500 error) by rewriting only when the URL is not of the form `/<something>/<something>/index.php`.

Comment: Sorry, in my haste there were a few errors! I've updated my answer with a tried and tested version! :)

Comment: Ok, but stil problems. I forgot to mention that I have more Top-level domains, not only .com. Sorry about that.

Comment: You're welcome, I updated it to make it completely generic. (Also, a second update avoids the trailing dot on a FQDN - this is optional)

Comment: Thank You so much for your time :) Everything is working just fine :)